# Sound notification in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal

When running commands such as `bundle install` (for Ruby apps), I'd like to hear a small sound (or popup) notification when the command finishes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the tool 'beep'.

```
$ sudo apt-get install beep
```

Now you append "; beep" to whatever command you run.

```
$ bundle install; beep
```

Comment: Also, I am aware that Konsole (from KDE) has this feature.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 13.10 is alpha and if your internal speaker is disabled you should enable it for this to work. Here is the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep).

Comment: I installed it, but it didn't work for me on Lubuntu 12.10. So I used "rhythmbox-client --play" command. It launches rhythmox and plays last song

Answer (score 5):

To get a pop-up notification, you can use notify-send. This gives you a notification using the same bubble pop-up as you see the OS using for new mail, etc. It is non-modal, so it will only last for a set amount of time though. You can extend the amount of time with the -t option.

Zenity will give you a modal pop-up than you can clear manually. Use something like:

```
zenity --info --text="message text"
```